# SQL Server 2005 sysdate conversion

Tags: sql-server-2005

FROM:  `4/13/2010 12:00:00 AM`
TO:    `4/13/2010`

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, EventDate, 101) AS EVENTDATE
FROM   db_Emp.dbo.tbl_EventsTable
WHERE  (EventDate BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2010-04-30')
```

I am expecting 50 total but the results is only 10 total.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do 40 of your records have an event date of 2010-04-30?  The time defaults to midnight, so the BETWEEN will exclude those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `'2010-04-30'` actually means `2010-04-30 00:00`

Try this perhaps?

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE MONTH(EventDate) = 4 
AND YEAR(EventDate) = 2010
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE EventDate BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2010-04-30 23:59:59.999'
```

Comment: The first one isn't sargable and the second one won't work. It would need to be `'2010-04-30 23:59:59.997'` to avoid being rounded up. Even then it could break if the OP upgrades to 2008 and uses higher precision datatypes. `WHERE EventDate >= '2010-04-01' AND  EventDate <  '2010-05-01'` is the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get all the dates of events in April, 2010 you can do it like this.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, EventDate, 101) 
FROM db_Emp.dbo.tbl_EventsTable
WHERE EventDate LIKE 'Apr%2010%'
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause won't work - `EventDate` is a regular `DATETIME` and does **not** look anything like `Apr%2010%` I'd think.... plus: the 101 style for `CONVERT` converts the `EventDate` to something like `03/23/2011` - no sign of "April" or "March" or anything like that....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, EventDate, 101) AS EVENTDATE
FROM   db_Emp.dbo.tbl_EventsTable
WHERE EventDate >= '2010-04-01' AND EventDate < '2010-05-01'
```